# Generate emails using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have two sub classes
1. Get gmail browser released updates.
2. Generate emails.

Im going to run above both class under main class. I need to know how i can  submit sub class 1 results to email body using method (string)

Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

Return the objects from subclass 1 and pass 
Create a method in subclass 1 to get the object references.
Create a method in subclass 2 to accept as inputs those object references.